# converting string of bytes to a byte array

Tags: .net

Having a hard time converting a string of bytes "23,200,237,15" into it's byte equivalent in .net.  Tried several different ways and trying to stick with splits.  Bitconverter seems way too inefficient for this.

Comment: Please post what you've tried, and what went wrong. You're having an error, or different results than expected? Please be specific.

Comment: There's not an error, I can't quite figure out the logic / keywords to get it done.

Answer (score 0):

There are soooo many ways to go about this...here's one basic approach:

```
    Dim strBytes As String = "23,200,237,15"

    Dim lstBytes As New List(Of Byte)
    For Each strByte As String In strBytes.Split(",".ToCharArray)
        Dim b As Byte
        If Byte.TryParse(strByte, b) Then
            lstBytes.Add(b)
        Else
            MessageBox.Show("Invalid Byte: " & strByte)
        End If
    Next

    ' use 'lstBytes' directly, or convert it to an array:
    Dim arrBytes() As Byte = lstBytes.ToArray
```

*You can get really fancy with these types of things using LINQ and end up with a one-liner that does it all.

Comment: Awesome, I think the tryparse was what I was missing.  Will try parsing your example ;)

Answer (score -1):

you can use this.

const string input = "stack overflow is good";

```
// Invoke GetBytes method.
// ... You can store this array as a field!
byte[] array = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(input);
```

Comment: You're taking a string and converting it, I'm looking for the exact digits to be transformed into the byte.  For example, the string "23" to be converted in to the byte 23.